# React Jest console is showing a different value for markup

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have created a test case as below -

```
 it('should return correct heading', () => {
        const wrapper = mount(
            <Provider store={store}><BrowseList name="BrowserList" /></Provider>
        );
        const heading = wrapper.find('.page-header-text');

        expect(heading.find('h1').text()).toEqual('Browse List');
```

On my screen, I see the value of h1 as "Browse List" which is expected (HTML DOM). When I `console.log(heading.debug())` it gives me the value of heading as "BrowseList", below is the snippet -

```
 <div className="page-header-text pull-left">
        <h1>
          BrowseList
        </h1>
      </div>
```

I was expecting it to come as "Browser List", but since it is coming as "BrowserList" my test case is failing. I am using react-i18next and **BrowserList** is the key that I am passing t("BrowserList")

Comment: I have a guts feeling that on the browser, you are getting one language but on the test you are getting anther one (most likely null). Therefore `react-i18` doesn't translate it, instead it just used your key.

Comment: Yes very likely, any idea on how to handle?

Comment: enclosing my component with `I18nextProvider` helped.